# How do I make a box group around Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

How do I box group Geometry Nodes like the example below?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The box is called a *Frame*

You can *Frame* Nodes by using the hotkeys <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

You can change the name of *Frame* Nodes by right clicking and navigating to Rename

More Information:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/nodes/frame.html

[image]